# Error Creating Stored Procedure in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure I am trying to create:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [cih_owner].[UpdateDisplayOrder]
    @CbpTableName varchar (21), 
    @CbpObjId int,
    @CbpId int,
    @DisplayOrder int
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@CbpTableName = "CbpActivity")
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [cih_owner].[CbpActivity] SET DisplayOrder = @DisplayOrder WHERE Id = @CbpObjId AND CbpId = @CbpId
        ;
    END
END
GO
```

However, in line that reads:
`(@CbpTableName = "CbpActivity")`
I get squigglies under 
`"CbpActivity"`
with the error
`Invalid column name 'CbpActivity'`

All I am trying to do is compare a string that I sent to the stored procedure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use apostrophes instead of quotations for string literals:

```
IF (@CbpTableName = 'CbpActivity')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to modified the `"` for `'` like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [cih_owner].[UpdateDisplayOrder]
    @CbpTableName varchar (21), 
    @CbpObjId int,
    @CbpId int,
    @DisplayOrder int
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@CbpTableName = 'CbpActivity')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [cih_owner].[CbpActivity] SET DisplayOrder = @DisplayOrder WHERE Id = @CbpObjId AND CbpId = @CbpId
        GO
    END
END
GO
```

Comment: Do you think the `GO` really still belongs in the middle of the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using single quote

```
IF (@CbpTableName = 'CbpActivity')
```

String are enclosed in single quotes in SQL